# Проверка наличия li.in в div.graphics

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в JS проверить, содержит ли div с ID graphics элемент списка li с классом in ? И, если содержит, присвоить div с ID graphics класс active

Спасибо! :)

Answer (score -1):

С [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) воттаквота:

```js
const $divgraphs = $('div#graphics');
if($divgraphs.find('li.in:first').length > 0){
    $divgraphs.addClass('active');
}else{
    $divgraphs.removeClass('active');
}
```

Если `li` дочерний\вложен в `div#graphics`, то вместо `find` используй `children`

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы active удалялся, если меняется класс у li?

Comment: А разве `length` может равняться -1?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko )))

Comment: @СергейДесфан добавил